# How WPF framework handles cyclic update of properties in MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Lets assume property Name is bind to TextBox in view like this.

```
private string name
public string Name
{
   get {return name;}
   set {
       name=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Name");
   }
}
```

View

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

When we update the text in text box, it will call the setter in Name property which in turn raise PropertyChanged which suppose to update UI again. I am curious how WPF avoid recursion of update and raise event. is it done by considering the sender of that event?

Answer (score 3):

A standard implementation of a property should look like this:

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
   get { return name; }

   set
   {
       if( name != value )
       {
           name = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Name");
       }
   }
}
```

Note the additional `if` to make sure the event is only raised if the value of the property actually changed.

Comment: I think you don't need this because OnPropertyChanged is internally cheking if new value is different.

Comment: OnPropertChanged is not a .NET function. So if you wrote it that way in *your* application, then you are right. But that would be totally inefficient because it would have to use reflection to get a property you already knew about earlier.

Comment: Yes, but I was assuming that it is internally calling PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"))

Comment: So did I. That's an event. The listeners will handle the event in any way they see fit. However, telling someone a value has changed when in fact it hasn't, hoping that the listener will check it for himself again and come to the same conclusion you already came to earlier in the process is very bad style.

Comment: Thanks and Yeah, I miss that point and we can avoid recursion using IF, but still it does not fully answer the question, that is even though you remove IF condition. Still it will not go to recursively infinite loop, which should happen, if it is not handle, I just wanted to know where is it handled?

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursion as far I understand.

1) TextBox updates the value using viewmodel property.

2) Viewmodel raises update, letting UI know that something changed

3) TextBox now updates himself to match the viewmodel value.

Comment: There is no 4th step. It's not needed becase in the first step, TextBox already has the new value(internally stored), and it won't "retrigger" same update to viewmodel twice. It has simple check in place. That's why you sometimes need to do "var x=Property; Property=null; Property=x;" to "retrigger" binding mechanism, since it has internally stored same value. (eg the Property=_samePropertyValue won't just cut it)

Comment: No, that's why you should check for the property value actually changing inside the setter itself.  You don't work around erroneous PropertyChanged notifications in your own code, you just make the notifications correct in the first place.  I would also note that you didn't mention any of that in your answer.  Per your own description there is most certainly infinite recursion.

Comment: I am sorry if my idea didn't get across. This thread has nothing to do with correcting your own notifications. User asked how does binding work under the hood and how it avoids such recursion cases. Simple.

Comment: *"and how it avoids such recursion cases. Simple."* - Yes, one would think.

Comment: I think I got your idea, we can avoid this recursion in different places like pointed by @nvoigt. yeah TextBox class internally might have handled this by treating differently to textbox text update event and propertychanged events. But I just wanted to know where it really happens and how? And I appreciate, if you can show with code fragment with dependancy property to emulate how it avoids recursion internally. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

may the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947380/why-wpf-binding-handles-inotifypropertychanged-in-two-different-ways) help you out.

if you set a property from ui to viewmodel it goes like this.

- setter call started
- value set
- INotifyPropertyChanged started
- INotifyPropertyChanged done
- setter done
- getter called and done
- IDataErrorInfo called and done

but if you set the property in your viewmodel it goes like this

- setter call started
- value set
- INotifyPropertyChanged started
- getter called and done
- IDataErrorInfo called and done
- INotifyPropertyChanged done
- setter done

> Changing property from UI to ViewModel may lead to deadlock kind of
>   situation which might run into end less recursive calls in two way
>   scenarios. In order to block this from happening, when WPF is making
>   change to model, it will continue to track changes via
>   INotifyPropertyChanged ,but this change will be queued in dispatcher
>   queue, and it will be executed after its current update is finished.
>
> Since the change in viewmodel is not initiated by WPF, WPF will not
>   queue the operation, it will immediately execute the change.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, you got my question but explanation is not clear for me. "when WPF is making change to model, it will continue to track changes via INotifyPropertyChanged ,but this change will be queued in dispatcher queue, and it will be executed after its current update is finished". What does I feel is, when it process these queued items, it will again raise event and continue to infinite loop. How does it handled in framework?